# Average timestamp in one column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to find the average of the order that came:

| Order_Date |
| --- |
| 2022-06-02 15:40:00 UTC |
| 2022-06-07 11:01:00 UTC |
| 2022-06-21 10:55:00 UTC |
| 2022-06-23 14:44:00 UTC |

Outcome:

average Order_Date *that came

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the `AVG()` average function over your entire table:

```sql
SELECT AVG(Order_Date) AS Avg_Order_Date
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Average timestamp** is unusual ask! But anyway, formally you can do below

```
select 
  timestamp_seconds(cast(avg(unix_seconds(timestamp(Order_date))) as int64)) as average_Order_Date
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: *Supported signatures for AVG: AVG(INT64); AVG(FLOAT64); AVG(NUMERIC); AVG(BIGNUMERIC); AVG(INTERVAL) - that is why you need all this back and forth "translations"*

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTE as
(
SELECT Order_Date, LAG(Order_Date,1) OVER(ORDER BY Order_Date ASC) as Datelag
FROM table
),
CTE2 as
(
SELECT Order_Date, datetime_diff(Order_Date,Datelag,hour) as Datedif
FROM CTE
)
SELECT AVG(Datedif)
FROM CTE2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).