# Calculate average and max time from a timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to calculate average and max of the time from timestamp in Bigquery.

Timestamp-

2022-01-24T23:14:25.883233

2022-01-24T22:14:25.883233

2022-02-24T21:14:25.883233

I am expecting result of the avg of (23:14:25.883233,22:14:25.883233,21:14:25.883233) that may come around 22:something

and max of these 3 times will be 23:14:25.883233.

I tried cast and unix_timestamp function but couldn't succeed

Comment: this would be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72780670/average-timestamp-in-one-column-in-bigquery

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. But I want to find the avg of a time from the timestamp. Not the whole timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT ts FROM UNNEST([
    TIMESTAMP '2022-01-24T23:14:25.883233', '2022-01-24T22:14:25.883233', '2022-02-24T21:14:25.883233'
  ]) ts  
)
SELECT TIME_ADD(TIME '00:00:00', INTERVAL CAST(AVG(time_in_usec) AS INT64) MICROSECOND) AS avg_time,
       TIME_ADD(TIME '00:00:00', INTERVAL MAX(time_in_usec) MICROSECOND) AS max_time
  FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY), MICROSECOND) time_in_usec 
      FROM sample_data
  );
```

[image]